# VPS server almost full (of images). Looking for solutions

Tags: php, amazon-s3, cloud, hosting, google-cloud-storage

I have a PHP website with thousands of users. They upload images everyday. Currently we have 250,000 images and our VPS hosting (Godaddy) is almost full (99%).

We are looking for a solution to this given that godaddy charges a lot for a bit of more space in our VPS.

What services are available to store images that we could integrate in our godaddy VPS? Maybe some cloud storage service? The content is static. We only generate thumbnails in many different sizes for every image uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 and here's their guide for the AWS-SDK

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html

Comment: Okay, but do they charge for space and/or bandwith usage?

Comment: "AWS Free Usage Tier*
As part of the AWS Free Usage Tier, you can get started with Amazon S3 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 standard storage, 20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests, and 15GB of data transfer out each month for one year."

Comment: The nice thing is that it SCALES.  You won't be put into the position that you are in today that you don't have enough space.

Comment: I haven't tried Google Cloud out.  I have tried IBM BlueMix.

Comment: Looks like it possibly - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/images

Comment: I'm seeing that Amazon has storage in Sao Paulo, this could be useful as my site is used by people in South America and Spain, mostly.

Comment: This is how you can read and write files to the google app engine via php https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/